# What free backup tool can be used with Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: backup, exchange

I am looking for a free Windows tool for backing up either my Exchange mailbox, which I access via Outlook (including calendar and contacts), or the whole Exchange database.

Using the built-in Windows Backup (wbadmin.msc) is not an option, because

- It does not allow backing up only Exchange. One must choose to backup the whole system to do it.
- I did not manage to perform it because of strange errors (something about missing system writer)

Answer (score 0):

[This Python script](https://github.com/utapyngo/outlook_backup/blob/master/oback.py) can backup user's mailbox including calendar and contacts into a PST file.
Python and [win32com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) are required to use it.